# passing pretty json into a textarea in angular

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make prettier the string in my text area in angular, brought from the database. It's an object that I send as a string and store it in my database. I introduced the ang-jsoneditor, but I need to validate it in case there are, for example,  missing quotes in the key. Before, I had a textarea and the validation was super-easy using validatorFn from angular.

What I have is this:

in my html:

```
<form fxLayout="column" [formGroup]="configForm">
    <div fxFlex="1 0 auto" fxLayout="column">
      <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100">
        <mat-label>JSON File</mat-label>
        <textarea matInput type="text" placeholder="Compose the json file here" formControlName="appConfig"
          rows="15"></textarea>
        <mat-error>
          A valid JSON object is required.
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </form>
```

and this is what i have in my .ts

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.configForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      appConfig: ["", [Validators.required, this.isValidJSON]]
    });
    this.appManagementService.getDeviceAppConfig(this.deviceId).then(response => {
      this.configErrorMessage = null;
      this.lastUpdate = response.lastUpdate;
      this.configForm.setValue({ appConfig: JSON.parse(response.config) });
    }).catch(() => {
      this.configErrorMessage = "Oops, could not get the registry info.";
    });
  }

  private isValidJSON: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (!control.parent || !control) {
      return null;
    }

    const appConfig = control.parent.get("appConfig").value;
    console.log('appConfig', appConfig)
    try {
      JSON.parse(appConfig.toString());
      return null;
    } catch (error) {
      return { "jsonInvalid": true };
    }
  }
```

when I pass a JSON.parse what it appears in my textarea is [object object]. How can I do to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

Try using JSON.stringify();

```
this.configForm.setValue({ appConfig: JSON.stringify(response.config) });
```

you can also use : `this.configForm.controls['appConfig'].setValue(JSON.stringify(response.config))`;